# What does Visual Studio's "Add reference" actually do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, build-system

I'm playing around with build systems and more specifically with **MSBuild** and Visual Studio 2019. I'm working with C++ and I'm trying to learn what is happening deeply behind the scenes. I was examining the **.sln** and **.vcxproj** files and the relationship between them. Now, both files are xml files that describe properties for the MSBuild system. I have a very simple setup:

[image: solution-setup]

A Visual Studio solution containing:

- CppTesting project (Content type - Application, .exe)
- Library project (Content type - Static Library, .lib)

By right clicking the CppTesting project VS presents me with the option to "Add reference" to my Library project. In other words to link my CppTesting project with the Library project. After I added the reference I examined both the **CppTesting.vcxproj** and the **Library.vcxproj** files and I noticed that the reference is not described in either of them. I could not find it in the **.sln** file either.

My question is: What exactly happens when I use the "**Add reference**" option in VS. Where is the reference described?

I'm looking for something like "CppTesting references Library" in some xml file. I tried looking at the C/C++ section of the projects, the Linker section. Could not find where this dependency is described. The official documentation I found does not go deep enough and it doesn't provide me with answers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=vs-2019

**EDIT:** SOLVED. It appears that the referenced library (Library.vcxproj) was not present in any of the XMLs, because it was empty (Or I was silly enough not to save my project changes). Anyway, I added some code to it, saved the solution and its projects and I got this (which was the expected result):

[image]

Comment: References are added to the project (e.g. .csproj) files: `<ItemGroup <PackageReference ...`.

Comment: Hello, in my case it's not a .csproj but a .vcxproj. It's a lengthy xml and I examined it carefuly, could not find any mentions of the Library referenced by it. I tried looking for the Library.vcxproj guid, it's name, but nothing.

Comment: @ChristianRizov Any update for this issue? It seems you've got it resolved, please consider sharing your discovery and workaround as answer, just a reminded:)

Comment: Hello, 

Yes, the "issue" was resolved. Since I'm not posting very often I'm not sure what the guidelines are. Decided to keep the question up since it might be insightful to people.

Cheers.

Comment: See [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), It seems you've found some useful info which help resolve your own question, you can add your own answer below and mark it to indicate this issue is solved, then people which search for similar topic can more easily find the marked solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution file, the various project files are just text files (more specifically XML files). These files contain information for the build system (**MSBUILD**) and are "consumed" by it. In the general case when you use the UI that **Visual Studio** provides you are just modifying that XML files (modifying the input you give the build system). My initial question was born because I could not find any trace of references in the project files when using the "**Add reference**" functionality that VS provides and I got confused. Turns out that I haven't properly saved my project files/solution and the references were missing.

Bonus note: The latest versions of Visual Studio support other build systems like **CMake**.

Answer (score 1):

**Add reference** is used to add references dll and your project in solution.
To see the reference, right click your project and then click **unload project**, then again right click your project and click edit yourproject.csproj.
You will find all references there.

Comment: Hello, my issue was that the references were not present in the XML files. I don't know if it was because my static library was empty or something else, but in the end, I managed to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to project and solution files do not happen immediately. When you make changes to a project or solution from within Visual Studio you can force the files to be updated by doing a Ctrl + Shift + S or a Save All from the file menu.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it appears I did not save properly or I did something else equally silly. In the end, the reference was present in the file just like I expected it to be.